# Prove: $|\{(x,y)\in \Bbb F_q^2 : y^2 = Q(x) \}|=q-1$ in a finite field

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, finite-fields

Let $\Bbb F_q$ be a finite field with q elements, with q odd. For a quadratic polynomial $Q(T)=T^2+a \in \Bbb F_q[T]$, show that if $a \neq 0$, then: 
$$|\{(x,y)\in \Bbb F_q^2 : y^2 = Q(x) \}|=q-1$$

---

If $a$ is a quadratic residue, then we have $q-1$ solutions of the form: $(0,b),(b,0)$ when $b$ is a quadratic residue. How do I show that those are the only solutions?
Also, what if $a$ is not a quadratic residue?

Comment: I didn't mention this in my answer, but I think you need to recheck your statement implying that, when $a$ is a quadratic residue, you always have solutions of the form $(0,b)$ and of the form $(b,0)$ and that this provides $q-1$ solutions. If $a=b^2$ is a quadratic residue then $(x,y)=(0,b)$ is indeed a solution to $y^2=x^2+a$, as is $(0,-b)$. If $-a$ is also a quadratic residue, which it will be when $q\equiv1\pmod{4}$, then $(c,0)$ and $(-c,0)$ will be solutions, where $c^2=-a$. This gives at most four solutions. If $-a$ is not a quadratic residue, then you'll only get two solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at an example, say $\mathbf{F}_5$ and $Q(x)=x^2+2$.  Now $2=1\cdot2=2\cdot1=3\cdot4=4\cdot3$.  We can convert each of these products to a solution, and there are $5-1=4$ of them.  For example, $2=4\cdot3=(1+3)(1-3)=1^2-3^2$ so that $(3,1)$ is a solution.  Similarly $2=1\cdot2=(4+2)(4-2)=4^2-2^2$ so that $(2,4)$ is a solution.

This can be generalized to any finite field of odd characteristic and any $a$.  Note that odd characteristic is required when writing each product as the difference of two squares.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the generalization; why are there $q-1$ ways to write $a$ as the difference of two squares?

Comment: There are $q-1$ ways to write $a$ as a product, $a=rs$ (because $s=a/r$ makes sense for any non-zero $r$).  Now you want to let $r=y+x$ and $s=y-x$.  This system of linear equations always has a unique solution when the field is of odd characteristic.